# VSTS Online Portal: Un-Nesting Build Folders on Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to set up automatic build + deploy for a rather large solution. The single solution produces 2 zip folders in the "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" location, and these contain all the right files. For the purposes of testing/troubleshooting I am only looking at one of these zip files, but eventually both sites will have to be deployed this way.

However, to get to the actual files, you have to pass through **14** unnecessary subfolders. To further complicate matters, about 8 of these are variable, based on certain elements of the build configuration (some are due to folder structure in the git repo).

I don't want any of these subfolders. The other problem is that I don't actually want a 100% flat file; I need 2 folders with subfolders to be contained within the finally-extracted directory. (The final directory is a physical path for an IIS site.) Is there any way to do this?

I have tried:

- Taking the generated zip file, extracting it to a temp directory, and repackaging it, all on the build machine.

  - To get this to work, I had to manually specify the 14 subdirectories. Also, I was unable to use "Publish Artifact" to upload the resulting zip to VSTS, so I'm not sure how to get it onto the server box.
- Downloading the published zip file from VSTS, extracting it locally on the release machine, and then copying the contents to the correct directory.

  - This works only when I manually specify the 14 folders contained in the directory. I made an attempt to hide the 14 folders with wildcards but only succeeded in copying the excessive nesting structure - I'm guessing the "Source Folder" parameter doesn't support wildcards (I had to actually do it in the "Contents" section or the task failed).
- Using the "Flatten Folders" advanced option in the copy dialog.

  - This removes ALL folder structure, which is not what I want. I need to end up with 2 folders containing subfolders in the final directory.

If it's not possible to only partially flatten the zip generated by the build step, I'd appreciate some help figuring out how much of this terribly convoluted path I can pull out using variables.

Comment: What's the result after trying my solution?

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way to move the contents of **only the contents and subdirectories** the `PackageTmp` folder to the build artifacts folder while shedding the unnecessary folder structure above it, and without using the "Flatten Folders" option (since you likely want to keep the folder structure under `PackageTmp` intact):

First, in your Build Solution task, set the MS Build Arguments similar to the following:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.binariesdirectory)"
```

Notice that `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=false` is set to false; you don't want to zip the package up just yet.  Also note the setting `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.binariesdirectory)`. You don't want the output to go directly to the artifact staging directory, as is configured by default.

Next, add a Powershell task, and add this inline script:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path '.\*' -Include 'PackageTmp' -Recurse
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PathToPackageTmpFolder]$($folder.FullName)"
```

This will store the fully qualified path to the `PackageTmp` folder in a variable named `PathToPackageTmpFolder`.  Under Advanced options, set the Working Directory to `$(build.binariesdirectory)`

Now add a Copy Files task to move only the contents of PackageTmp and its subfolders to the artifact staging directory.  Set Source Folder to `$(PathToPackageTmpFolder)`, Contents to `**`, and Target Folder to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.  You're all set!

Comment: I managed to get all this working right up until the step where I deploy to an azure app service, but I'm not sure how to get it to deploy properly. Do I need to publish the artifact first?  .    
`- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4  
  inputs:  
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'  
    azureSubscription: 'myAzureSubscription'  
    appType: 'webAppLinux'  
    WebAppName: 'myWebAppName'  
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**'  
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'`

Answer (score 2):

That is the MSBuild deploy/publish to package action and the folder structure won’t be remain after deploying to the server.

You can specify `/p:PackageTempRootDir=""` msbuild argument to ignore the folder structure of project path.

Another way is that, you can publish project through FileSystem method, then archive files through Archive files task.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the folder structure won't remain after deploying to the server" -- it very much does, and that is 100% of the problem. I have to extract the zip files (just deploying them with IIS doesn't put the files where they need to be). I think the PackageTempRootDir parameter will *help*, but it still doesn't really solve the problem I have. It just reduces the number of extra nested folders I have to ~4.

Comment: @thecoloryes How do you deploy package to IIS? With WinRM IIS Web App Deployment or Azure Web App Deployment task, just the published result files are deployed to the server without the extra nested folders. With /p:PackageTempRootDir="" msbuild argument, it removes the folder structure of the project path, but has Content\D_C\PackageTmp. You can publish project through FileSystem method.

Comment: I use the "IIS Web App Deploy(Preview)" task in my release definition. I couldn't do it from the build definition because the build and release machines are not only unique but in different domains, so I can't get WinRM on the build machine to communicate with the release machine. Originally I wanted to use the FileSystem publish to a shared network drive but the "Copy Files" task had permissions issues writing to the shared drive, so I had to use the Server method. I think the argument you mentioned is the closest I'll get to what I really want.

Comment: @thecoloryes Feel free to use IIS Web App Deploy task in release. You also can publish to artifact folder with FileSystem publish method, then publish the files to Server. BTW, there is Windows Machine File copy task that can used to copy files to another machine.

Comment: note that /p:PackageTempRootDir="" will write the package temp files to the root of your drive, which can be a big problem if multiple builds are run on the server at the same time.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT The fundamental problem here is that there is an assumption that you want to deploy to IIS or Azure.  If you want target some other environment, the fact that the copy files features forces you to deal with your files being buried in an arbitrary folder structure with no variable that represents it puts you in a really tough spot.  At the very least, an option should be added to the copy files task that allows you to preserve folder structure from the target directory down.