# Copy File task error in Azure Devops ##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder:

Tags: azure-devops, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am getting a error at CopyFiles task in my Azure Devops Build Pipeline.

##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder:

[image]

This is my YAML script below, At copy task I am getting an ##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: Default

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
    ArtifactName: 'PublishBuildArtifacts'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'PublishBuildArtifacts'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\**/*PublishBuildArtifacts/Webapp.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\TestSite'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: true
    
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\TestSite\Content\F_C\vsts-agent-1\_work\626\s\Webapp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\DeployedAPP'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found the solution in the stack overflow.

[Answer to my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924305/vsts-online-portal-un-nesting-build-folders-on-release)